# Pymongo Network TimeOut

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

I am using pool for multiprocessing in python and connecting to mongoDB. I am getting these error frequently.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
 pymongo.errors.NetworkTimeout: mongoDb:port number : timed out
```